# how to drop nan values but not colums in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas in which i want to drop n/a value but columns it looks like this

```
A   B   C
---------
0  Nan Nan
Nan 1  Nan
Nan Nan 2
```

and i want it to look like this.

```
A B C
-----
0 1 2
```

is there a method for that in pandas

Comment: Can there be more than one non-NaN value in each column? If there is, which one do you want in the output?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single non-NaN per column you could [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and slice the first row:

```
out = df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
```

Or [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) (credit to @Nick):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.max()).T
```

Or [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
out = df.stack().droplevel(0).to_frame(0).T
```

Or [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
out = df.groupby([0]*len(df)).first()
```

If those values are only on the diagonal, use [`numpy.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html):

```
out = pd.DataFrame([np.diag(df)], columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

##### timings

On a 1000 x 1000 diagonal array.

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(df.max()).T
1.4 ms ± 8.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
3.53 ms ± 66.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.stack().droplevel(0).to_frame(0).T
10.2 ms ± 44.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby([0]*len(df)).first()
76.1 ms ± 313 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame([np.diag(df)], columns=df.columns)
8.73 ms ± 27.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: May as well add `pd.DataFrame(df.max()).T` to that list...

Comment: @Nick that's indeed a possibility, I ended up with multiple ways as I thought of them while writing my first approach ;)

Comment: I wonder if `bfill` or `max` is more efficient...

Comment: @Nick `max` is faster :)

Comment: ah cool. I should have posted it! :)

Comment: @Nick you can if you like and remove it from my answer

Comment: No no no much better to have them all in one place

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
     A    B    C
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  2.0
3  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  5.0  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

You can use:

```
# It works only if the first value of the group is A
out = df.groupby(df['A'].notna().cumsum(), as_index=False).max()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     A    B    C
0  0.0  1.0  2.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

**Edit**

A more robust solution:

```
arr = np.ravel(df)
arr = arr[~np.isnan(arr)].reshape(-1, len(df.columns))
out = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the dataset you provided:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""
A   B   C
0   nan nan
nan 1   nan
nan nan 2
"""))
```

A clean way to do it is:

```
df.melt().dropna().set_index("variable").T
```

It first normalizes the dataframe to remove unwanted dimensions, then it reshapes it.